# Adding PDF plot inside README.md on github

Tags: github, github-pages

I am writing my analysis report on GitHub using the `README.md` page.

I was successfully able to create tables and add necessary text to the page, but couldn't find a way to actually display my PDF plots inside the README.

My plots are inside my git  repo, has anyone tried doing something similar before?

Comment: Does my post below answered your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By PDF plot, I assume you mean [Probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) plots, not the [Adobe Portable Document Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format).

You cannot render pdf plots directly in a `README`. The workaround for now is to render it as an image (png for instance) and [include that image in the `README.md` markdown file, using a relative link](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#relative-links).